# Reopening questions, possible bug

Tags: bug, review

In the review queue I was asked to decide whether to reopen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944199/are-paradoxes-a-threat-against-mathematics) question or not.

Some times I click to reopen because after doing so I'm asked if I really want to do it and I gain access to the whole thread instead of just the question. I did it this time and it simply reopened without confirmation.

So what's up with this?

Comment: It's funny, I thought that when the whole thread popped up *that* was the unwanted behavior (because why display it when there's a dialog box preventing you from scrolling and seeing everything).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You can click on the cross to close the pop up window (which will allow you to scroll) without having to commit to a decision and then click on the blue buttons on top as you see fit.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But it's still a very weird behavior, either that information is useful for you to make a decision and it should be displayed from the beginning, or it's not and it shouldn't be displayed at all. As it is it's displayed when you've already shown that you've taken a decision, it's very strange.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Well, I know it happens so I exploit(ed) it without having made a decision.

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer to our question, but you might want to give [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) a try; one of the more interesting fixes it includes is [showing answers to questions in the review queues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue).